# How to set dynamically default value for DropDownListFor using asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

Dynamically i should load dropdown list and display the selected value. but dropdown loaded sucessfully but default value not selected.

@gt.PlantId - integer,
PlantId -integer

```
        @foreach (var gt in Model.RoleList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Plants,new SelectList(Model.Plants,"PlantId","PlantName", @gt.PlantId))</td>
                <td>@gt.PlantId</td>
                <td>@gt.RoleId</td>
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("deletedet", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "Edit-User", AllowCache = true, InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith }))
                {
                    @Html.Hidden("userId", @gt.UserId)

                <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myTable"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p></td>
                }
            </tr>

        }
```

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"), "DEFAULT VALUE GOES HERE", new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: Try above and make changes accordingly. "DEAFULT VALUE GOES HERE" Replace it with what you want as default

Comment: Hi Unbreakable, Thank you very much. based on value i have to display the text. when i enter "DEFAULT VALUE GOES HERE" in this my id i'm getting error like cant convert into to string

Comment: `<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Plants,new 
SelectList(Model.Plants,"PlantId","PlantName", Model.Plants))</td>`

Comment: Did it work...?

Comment: yes. but default text its not coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If foreach loop `@Html.DropDownListFor ,@Html.HidenFor, @Html.TextBoxFor` or any other input element never working,
 because in razor `input/select/textarea` create a unique html `name/id` attribute. But using `foreach` it can't do this. 
 so use for loop or EditorTemplates rather than foreach.

Other wise you can generate the html but you can't send list of item in your action.

**Example:**

**Model:**

```
public class UserEditorViewModel
    {
       public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string RoleId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

`EditorTemplates` need to exist in either `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` or `Views/ControllerName/EditorTemplates` and name of the view (by default) should be the name of the `object(Or Name of the Model)` you want to use it as the template.

**Editortemplates:**

> Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/UserEditorViewModel.cshtml

```
@model UserEditorViewModel

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.UserId)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserId)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.UserName)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RoleId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleId, new SelectList(Model.Roles,"RoleId","RoleName",Model.RoleId))
</div>
```

**View :**

```
@model UserEditorViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("--Your Action--", "--Your Controller--"))//Or use Ajax.BeginForm if you need
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: Hi Friend, Thank you very much. its working fine one more problem is i want to save the all changed dropdownlist value. for example one user it will come multiple roles and departments dropdownlist i want to save all the dropdown values. can you help me please.

Comment: Simple  your action receive something like `ActionName(List<UserEditorViewModel> model) `.@SENA